# Upload file to server outside codeigniter path

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am trying to move file outside Codeigniter path like "/home/uploads" using move_uploaded_file or copy but both method doesn't work!

I uploaded the files by using Grocery Crud library & tried to move file using callback_after_upload.

in Grocery Crud Controller:

```
 $crud->callback_after_upload(array($this, 'upload'));
```

and in the callback function:

```
function upload($uploader_response,$field_info, $files_to_upload){
ini_set("display_errors",1);
$baseURl = site_url();
            $upload_config['upload_path'] = ''; 
$file_uploaded = $field_info->upload_path.'/'.$uploader_response[0]->name; 
copy($file_uploaded, "/home/uploads/");
```

any help please!

Comment: Unless you're running your script from the root directory of the server (you're not...), `home/uploads` and `/home/uploads` are two completely different directories. You should check the exact path and file permissions for that path.

Comment: Thanks @jeroen edited, I am using ( /home/uploads/ ) in my script, just , how to check if I have the permission to upload in that path, noting that the file "uploads" have 777 permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to include the filename in the destination

```
copy($file_uploaded, "/home/uploads/".$uploader_response[0]->name);
```

`move_uploaded_file()` is probably more appropriate as it won't leave a file in the upload folder like `copy()` does. Again, include the file's name in the destination.

Comment: lol .. I think that I tried it and it didn't work .. but now its working 
Thanks a lot @DFriend ...